# Skip test method results in testng report

Tags: java, testng

I have a question about testng.

I have something like:

```
@Test
public initializeMethod() {
//here I do something that is needed before my real test method
}

@Test (depends on initializeMethod) 
public myRealTest1{
//my test 1
}

@Test (depends on myRealTest1) 
public myRealTest2{
//my test 2
}
```

Is it possible to skip initializeMethod in testng report (I mean that in report I want to see real count of tests (2 but not 3))?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@Test` annotation is used specifically for the tests. You have to annotate the method `initializeMethod()` properly with a non-test [annotation](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#annotations). Several options are:

```
@BeforeTest
@BeforeClass
```

Other possible annotations:

```
@BeforeSuite
@BeforeGroups
@BeforeMethod // if you want `initializeMethod()` run before every test.
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to run initializeMethod() before each real Test method, you can use @BeforeMethod annotation.
@BeforeMethod: The annotated method will be run before each test method.
So, you need to declare the method as below:

```
@BeforeMethod
public initializeMethod() {
//here I do something that is needed before my real test method
}
```

If you want to run initializeMethod() only once, you can use @BeforeClass annotation.
@BeforeClass: The annotated method will be run before the first test method in the current class is invoked.
So, you need to declare the method as below:

```
@BeforeClass
public initializeMethod() {
//here I do something that is needed before my real test method
}
```